# General Addition Rule for Probability extended to 4 events?

Tags: probability

I just started statistics and need to use the general addition rule. I know what it looks like for $3$ events:

$$P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B) - P(A \cap C) - P(B \cap C) - (2 * P(A \cap B \cap C)) + P(A'\cup B' \cup C').$$

But I'm confused to exactly how it extends to 4 events?

Thanks.

Comment: To find $P(A\cup B\cup C\cup D)$: You first add all individual probabilities, then subtract all probabilities of events taken two at a time ($P(A\cap B)$, e.g.; there are other terms here...), then add all probabilities of events taken three at a time ($P(A\cap B\cap D)$, e.g.; note there are three other terms here), and finally subtract the probability of the intersection of all events.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's this thing called the inclusion-exclusion identity, for any number $n$, this is the formula.

[image]

for a proof of how this is works, you can check out this link at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Answer (score 1):

The general formula is

$P\left( \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} A_i\right) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} P(A_i) - \sum\limits_{i, j : i < j} P(A_i \cap A_j) + \sum\limits_{i, j, k : i < j < k} P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k) - ... + (-1)^{n-1} P\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n} A_i\right)$

When $n = 4$, we get

$P\left( \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{4} A_i\right) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{4} P(A_i) - \sum\limits_{i, j : i < j} P(A_i \cap A_j) + \sum\limits_{i, j, k : i < j < k} P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k) -  P\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{4} A_i\right)$

If we further assume the events $\{A_i\}$ to be **exchangeable**, we get

$P\left( \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} A_i\right) = n \times P(A_1) - {n \choose 2} \times P\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{2} A_i\right) +  {n \choose 3} \times P\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{3} A_i\right) - ... + (-1)^{n-1} P\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n} A_i\right)$

For $n = 4$ with exchangeable events, this gives

$P\left( \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{4} A_i\right) = 4 \times P(A_1) - 6 \times P\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{2} A_i\right) + 3 \times P\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{3} A_i\right) - P\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{4} A_i\right)$